# How to download an app's files and store them on an USB storage device to use it at every Linux distro?

Tags: software-installation, usb, portable

I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop, but my other PC has no access to the internet to download the apps I need.

How can I install these apps on a USB storage device and run them portably on the other PC?

Note that I don't have administrative rights on any other PC except for my laptop, so `sudo`, `apt` or `snap` are not available to me on the other PC?

Comment: If you "*dont have admin on any other pc*", then it's considered polite to ask the admin for permission to run your software. Folks take a dim view of running your cryptominer on their electric bill without being asked.

Comment: Assuming that the asker of this question does not want to run a cryptominer, more than 1000 open source apps have been ported to be run as portable apps on the Linux platform without requiring `sudo` permissions from the user.

Comment: @karel: "more than 1000 open source apps have been ported to be run as portable apps on the Linux platform without requiring sudo permissions from the user" , --> yesss, the only problem is without sudo, you need a bin file and those apps are just code -_-.

Comment: My AppImage files can be launched from the terminal without any problems. For more information see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

AppImages are self-contained apps which can simply be downloaded and run on any Linux distribution. AppImages can be run from a hard drive or from removable media by a regular user without using `sudo`. AppImages can be downloaded from [Appimagehub.com](https://www.appimagehub.com). The AppimageHub catalog currently has 1154 AppImages to choose from.

Make an AppImage file (e.g. *example.appimage*) executable as follows:

```
chmod a+x example.appimage
```

Run an AppImage file as follows (note that `sudo` is not required):

```
./example.appimage
```